# help compiling gcc-10-source with debian patches on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: compiling, gcc

After extracting `gcc-10-source_10.2.0-8ubuntu1_all.deb`,
I entred into dir `usr/src/gcc-10`, then issued the command:

```
$ debian/rules control
```

I downloaded the prerequisites in the folder `src/`
then created `build/` directory and `chdir` into it

I issued the configure command:

```
$ ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 10.2.0-8ubuntu1' --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-10/ --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-10 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none,hsa --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
```

then I begin compiling the source packages

```
$ LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib32 time make -j 8 | tee ../build-gcc-10.2.lo
```

But then after a while I got the error message:

```
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc... /home/nail/Documents/data/gcc/gcc-10.2/gcc-10-source_10.2.0-8ubuntu1/usr/src/gcc-10/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/nail/Documents/data/gcc/gcc-10.2/gcc-10-source_10.2.0-8ubuntu1/usr/src/gcc-10/build/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/gcc-10/x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/gcc-10/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/gcc-10/x86_64-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/gcc-10/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys-include -isystem /home/nail/Documents/data/gcc/gcc-10.2/gcc-10-source_10.2.0-8ubuntu1/usr/src/gcc-10/build/sys-include -fchecking=1  -m32
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/nail/Documents/data/gcc/gcc-10.2/gcc-10-source_10.2.0-8ubuntu1/usr/src/gcc-10/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/32/libgomp':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

For your information, if I extract the package `gcc-10.2.0.tar.xz` without debian patches and forgo the same procedure, the package compile fine without errors!

Comment: Looks like a permissions problem. https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld  may help. You seem to lack write permission on the directory where `gcc` wants to write its output. AFAIK, the way it's done is to copy the package source to your environment, apply patches, build, test, REPACKAGE, and install the `.deb`.

Comment: @waltinator it's not permissions problem! I run all the command (extract, patch, build) as normal user.